# Kibana not working after x-pack uninstalled

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I had installed x-pack earlier and used it, and hosted Kibana through Nginx.

I yesterday uninstalled x-pack from both elasticsearch and kibana, via 
`sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin remove x-pack`
and 
`sudo bin/kibana-plugin remove x-pack`

Now, when I try to start elastic, elastic is started, but Kibana does not start when I start kibana.

The `Kibana.stdout` log says,

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-04-27T06:23:39Z","tags":["info","optimize"],"pid":49497,"message":"Optimizing and caching bundles for kibana, timelion and status_page. This may take a few minutes"}
```

And Kibana is never started.

The `sudo service kibana status` says it is running, but `sudo netstat -ntlp`, I can not find the port `5601`.

It is never started. Why so ?

What can be the possible issue ?

Comment: How long did you wait? That task is usually taking some time.

Comment: around 10, 15 minutes

Comment: cannot connect to /var/run/nscd/socket

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the kibana/optimize/bundles directory as well as the kibana/optimize/.babel-cache.json file and restarting Kibana. That will trigger a completely fresh rebuild of the Kibana source without x-pack.

*Note: If you're using kibana as a system daemon, run the kibana process through the command line once to re-compile the optimize bundle before starting the daemon.

`./usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana`*